# Laravel - Bootstrap - NPM Watch is not replacing css matches, it's adding

Tags: npm, bootstrap-4, watch, laravel-8, scss-mixins

Laravel 8 - Bootstrap 4
I have two Laravel projects. One created and running in docker, the other created and running in Vagrant/Homestead. The setups are almost the same otherwise.

However, in my vagrant/homestead project, when I use variables in my app.scss file like these:

```
$theme-colors: (
    "blue":    #007bff,
    "indigo": #4B0082,
    "purple": #6d388c,
    "pink":    #e83e8c,
);
```

What compiles into my app.css file, is duplicated for the items above, like this:

```
:root {
  --blue: #3490dc;
  --indigo: #6574cd;
  --purple: #9561e2;
  --pink: #f66d9b;
  --blue: #007bff;
  --indigo: #4B0082;
  --purple: #6d388c;
  --pink: #e83e8c;
}
```

With my colors lower in the file. The end result is the same, as the lower variables take precedence, and they aren't double processed into the classes where they are included either.
It seems something is wrong, as this does not happen in my project on the docker install. Is it possible that the mixin (or...) rules changed to now include the duplicates? Hard to guess that is true.
I don't believe docker or vagrant has anything to do with this, I'm just using those specifics to keep clear which is which.
Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: did you set the variables at the top?, before the ```@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";'```
```@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";```

Comment: Yea. I did. And on another project it works fine. 
I can’t explain it.

Comment: tried recompiling the assets with ```npm run watch-poll``` to update the css?